# Windows Python Path

Tags: python, windows, path

I am having fits trying to understand why a Python script will not execute due to a package not being found. I am sure it is a path issue, but I do not know why or how to solve.

I have 2 scripts in a folder on the Desktop\scripts folder each needing to be executed by a .bat file on a schedule. One script works perfectly and the other errors on missing package "results". The one that works does not require the package.

I to my knowledge have 2 instances of python on the computer.

1. c:\users\root\venv\                 (used by pycharm)
2. c:\users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe

Both installs have a site-packages directory with "results" installed.

From c:\users\root\Desktop\scripts if I type python to enter the console and do `import results` it seems to load the module, but if I run python myfile.py I get the error module not found.

The folder scripts is a pycharm project folder, not sure if that has some effect and if I run the file from pycharm it executes fine.

If I run python from c:\users\root and enter `import results` in the console it also seems to load the module without error.

Comment: Show us the exact commands being executes by the .bat files.

Comment: @JohnGordon The .bat file doesn't seem to be a factor here, OP says that manually running `python myfile.py` already fails.

Comment: @Antimon The question says there are two installations of python.  The intent of my comment was to see what python interpreter is being used, i.e. do the commands in the .bat file say `python foo.py`, or `python3 foo.py`, etc.

Comment: @JohnGordon Still wouldn't explain why starting the python interpreter and importing the module behaves differently from using the same python interpreter and handing it myfile.py as an argument.

Comment: Make another script that just has `import sys; print(sys.path)` and run that with `python foo.py`.  What does it print?

Comment: I will tr the script mentioned. As far as the bat goes this is all that is in it ```@echo off

"C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" "C:\Users\root\Desktop\scripts\myFile.py"```

Comment: and as mentioned that path has the results package

Comment: C:\Users\root\Desktop\scripts>python testPath.py
['C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop\\scripts', 'C:\\Users\\root\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Users\\root\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\root\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\root\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38', 'C:\\Users\\root\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Okay, so `C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages` is in the path.  Is `results` installed in that directory?

Comment: I didn't notice it before BUT the actual path is ...\Lib\... not ...\lib\... otherwise the package is there. How can I fix that?

Comment: The correct solution is probably to re-install the `results` module so it gets placed in the right directory.  How did you install that module originally?

Comment: There are a lot of packages in that \Lib directory, not that I have installed them but they are there. \Lib seems to be the correct path, I am not sure why it has \lib

Comment: The package was installed via pip install results, so a path was not given during install.

Comment: If the module names don't collide, you can probably just move everything in `Lib` to `lib`.  But I wonder why pip installed things into `Lib` in the first place.

Comment: yeah, thats what I am concerned about

Comment: Looking into just using a venv, but I am unclear how to use that from a bat to execute the script.

Comment: So create a new venv and it created the directory \Lib and the path shows \lib...confused

Comment: Not sure why or what the difference is, but I was able to get it to work using the virtual enviornment.